# Jquery animation width and height setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zd7Vf/4/) code. Right now my animation is working fine but when i am replacing my image   with  [this image](http://i.share.pho.to/9f303156_o.jpeg). Then my animation is working in different way. I tired to set width and height as well but it does not work. I need my animation to work similar like now in fiddle.I have cropped the current image width and height to make it work but this is not a original image i do not want to crop my image. Can anyone tell me what i am missing here?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <p class="copy">Disclaimer.</p>
        <div id="text">
            <img id="Image_Car" class="container" src="http://i.share.pho.to/9f303156_o.jpeg" />

        </div>
        <div id="Div1">
            <p id="disclaimer">Details*</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually works fine for me with both images. Can you explain what you mean by "is working in a different way"?

Comment: the second image is working fine as well but you can see the width and height it is too small as compared to the image i am using

Comment: So is it you want the dress (2nd image) to appear bigger?

Comment: Second image is bigger then the first image and it have lot of white space in left hand size so if you try the reduce the image height and width, it will obviously look smaller, My recommendation is to use images of same dimensions.

Comment: i do not want to crop the image and i need to use the same image

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes:
1. In the html file include the image:

1. In css file:

   ## Image_Car{

   position:absolute;
   top:-20px;
   left:150px;
   right:140px;
   width: 250px;
   height: 260px;
   }

3.In jQuery:
    function bannerAnimation(){
    //Jquery Animation
    $("#Image_Car").animate({ width: "220px",
        height: "240px"
    }, 1000);

This will make it work as desired..